# Finding the intersections of straight lines

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

Given a set of lines intersecting the quadrant with $x, y>0$, what are the available algorithms for finding the area below all straight lines (including $y$ and $x$ axis)? In other words, methods to find the points of the polygon given be the intersections of the lines?

Comment: set equal this lines each other,did i guess correctly what did you mean?

Comment: I'm looking for algorithms to solve this problem in the most efficient way..

Comment: are you trying to find the area bounded by a set of lines and the x and y axes? by x,y > 0 do you mean that the x and y intercept of all lines in the set are positive?

Comment: The question is very confusingly written.  I think you are interested in the area of a polygon given in the form $Ax\le b$, $x\ge 0$, which you can do with fast convex hull algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you can compute the polygon you are interested in by dualizing, computing the convex hull, and then going back.  This is pretty standard course material, e.g., http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2012/cmsc754/Lects/lect08.pdf

Comment: Can the Graham's algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) be extended to the case when points are added or removed?

Comment: This seems like a different question that might be more appropriate for cs.SE.